# Moving Feature to a Fragment Throws Error

Tags: wix

I am new to WiX, but I have one issue that I can't figure out.  I have the following code which "installs" fine (basically it just adds a text file to the Program Files folder).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="WixTemplate" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="My Company" UpgradeCode="d7c4cfc2-4e50-4002-9273-e900112e2b03">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixTemplate" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixTemplate" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="TextFileComponent">
        <File Id="FooTxt" Source="foo.txt" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

However, if I move the **Feature** section to its own Fragment, it compiles fine, but when I run it with logging, it fails with an overall "Installation success or error status: 1603" and the first error value of 3 indicating "Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText" meaning that the ActionText table was not found.

Here is the code that fails to install:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="WixTemplate" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Blue Ribbon Technologies, LLC" UpgradeCode="d7c4cfc2-4e50-4002-9273-e900112e2b03">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixTemplate" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixTemplate" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="TextFileComponent">
        <File Id="FooTxt" Source="foo.txt" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

So what's special about the **Feature** section that it can't be a fragment where **Components** and **Directories** can?

Comment: A missing ActionText table doesn't typically cause a fatal 1603 error - it just goes ahead and displays the default data. Is there nothing else in the log? Perhaps post all of it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your Product references the Feature. WiX won't link in a Fragment unless something references a resource in it. Add a FeatureRef to your Product to pull in the Feature which will in turn pull in the ComponentGroup which pulls in the Component.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm surprised the the code passed the candle and light compilers/linkers without issue, but I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It's legal to have stuff that isn't referenced -- that's how you can build libraries. There is an error if you reference a component but don't connect it to a feature.